# How to install 'glpk' solver in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, solver, glpk

I just started working on an optimization problem with PyCharm using Pyomo (I'm new to it). I tried to install 'glpk' solver from Project Interpreter, but it returns "*ERROR: Failed building wheel for glpk* and *ERROR: Could not build wheels for glpk which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly*".

I use Mac, Python 3.7 and PyCharm 2020 CE. All the other packages are the latest version, e.g. pip, wheel, setuptools. I looked up some Q&A and it seems I didn't have the right path? But I don't know how to get it right. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import os
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory


model = ConcreteModel(name="Linear (H)")

A = ['I_C_Scoops', 'Peanuts']
h = {'I_C_Scoops': 1, 'Peanuts': 0.1}
d = {'I_C_Scoops': 5, 'Peanuts': 27}
c = {'I_C_Scoops': 3.14, 'Peanuts': 0.2718}
b = 12
u = {'I_C_Scoops': 100, 'Peanuts': 40.6}

def x_bounds(m, i):
    return (0,u[i])
model.x = Var(A, bounds=x_bounds)

def obj_rule(model):
    return sum(h[i]*(1 - u[i]/d[i]**2) * model.x[i] \
for i in A)

model.z = Objective(rule=obj_rule, sense=maximize)
model.budgetconstr = Constraint(expr = sum(c[i]*model.x[i] for i in A) <= b)

opt = SolverFactory('glpk')
results = opt.solve(model)
```

Comment: What about `python -m pip install glpk --no-use-pep517`?

Comment: Thank you. I installed Anaconda later and the solver was installed.

Comment: @JiajiaZheng I'm having a similar problem with Anaconda. It is not finding GLPK although i have it installed. How did you do it?